# Simple math question:

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I have a simple question.

I have two values MIN and MAX. Then i have a series of values (X) that can be between 0 and +infinity.

Now I want to have an algorithm that maps each value x of X into the range between MIN and MAX.

Comment: Most of the times yes, but it can be undeterministic

Comment: I assume you want a map that is one-to-one, otherwise the answer is trivial.

Comment: That depends on how you want them mapped. You can use `atan`, negative exponentials, and other more exotic mappings.

Comment: Does it matter what the mapping is? Is it OK if values "switch places" (i.e. a smaller input maps to a larger output)? Is it OK if the spacing between elements is disproportionate to what it was to start with? Do you need (I think this is what Kobi meant) to choose the mapping first and be able to handle any input that's thrown at it, or can you tailor the mapping according to the input?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Karl Knechtel The space between two values should be the same as in the original data serie (proportional)

Comment: Not a very well phrased question, but interesting from a programmer's viewpoint if considered for floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: You can't have that and simultaneously have a mapping that's chosen ahead of time and handles any input, because a mapping that keeps the space proportional must be an affine transform, and when X can be arbitrarily large, ax+b can only be kept from growing arbitrarily large (in absolute value) by setting a = 0.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: It is impossible to linearly map an infinite range onto a finite range.

Comment: In case anyone read my "not on math.stackexchange.com!" comment, please disregard it. I confused it with mathoverflow.net.

Comment: I'm sorry to see that this question was closed. Although its contents is mathematical, it's the kind of problem (concisely mapping one domain to another) that shows up all the time in software development.

Comment: @Gareth: Maybe, but as written it is woefully underspecified, and the OP ignored request for clarification for more than an hour before the close and for half a day since then. Various answer are that *will* work have been suggested in the comments and answers.

Comment: I disagree that the underspecification was severe enough to warrant closing. The question seemed clear enough to me, but then I often encounter and solve problems of this form myself. I expect it's a sign of inexperience on the part of the closers.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one that just uses basic arithmetic (no `atan` or `exp`):

> MAX + (MIN − MAX) / (1 + *x*)

If you need to vary the shape of this conformal mapping, try

> MAX + (MIN − MAX) / (1 + f(*x*))

for any positive function f (for example f(*x*) = *kx* or f(*x*) = √*x* or ...).

Answer (score 4):

MIN + atan(x)*(MAX-MIN)/(PI/2)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want a monotonically increasing function:

```
MAX + (MIN - MAX)*exp(-k*x)
```

Where `k` is a rate factor that determines how quickly the mapping approaches MAX.

Comment: This very quickly becomes `MAX` due to limited floating point precision.

Comment: @larsmans: Then make `k` small.

Comment: Fair enough. +1 for the edited version.

Comment: Surely that should be MAX - (MAX-MIN)exp(-kx)?